# Pyinstaller Windows enable or disable console at runtime

Tags: windows, console, pyinstaller

I have a Windows application built in Pyinstaller 3.2.1 that generally needs to run in windowed mode (no console). But advanced users can also execute it in command line mode by providing command line arguments.

The problem in the advanced use case is that with Pyinstaller's --windowed option my application's stdout and stderror are invisible making the command line use cumbersome.

Is there a clever way in Python and Pyinstaller to enable or disable the console when I execute the application?

Alternately, I tried building the application with --console option and suppressing the console on the OS level like

```
MyApp.exe 2>&1
```

This works but only when execute from the command line. If I place 2>&1 into the executable's shortcut target property the application crashes at launch. How could I make this work?